# /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 503, should be 0 - El Capitan

Tags: macos, sudo

Whenever I try any Sudo commands in terminal, I get the following error message:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 503, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

I have tried logging into single user mode and typing in the following commands:

```
mount -uw

chown /private/etc/sudoers 0
```

After typing in the chown ownership line, I get an error message saying

```
“illegal username”.
```

Other things I have tried:

- Reinstalling the os (El Capitan)
- Disabling System Integrity Protection (SIP).
- Calling Apple Care who say that Sudo commands have been disabled in El Capitan.
- Logging in under Single User mode and typing in the following code:

  - chown root:wheel /private/etc/sudoers

    - This produced the error message “Operation Not Permitted” in my Standard, Admin, and Root accounts.
    - The error message “Read-Only File System” came up when I logged tried the code in Single User Mode.

FYI

When I run `ls -la /private/etc/sudoers` in Terminal, I get the following:

```
-rw-r-----@ 1 MY-ADMIN-USERNAME staff 67 18 Feb 14:03 /private/etc/sudoers
```

Note I’ve replaced my actual admin username with “MY-ADMIN-USERNAME” just so you know what’s showing.

I need Sudo commands to work for a range of reasons, one of which is to get CrashPlan to work.

My hardware is a 2010 iMac, 3.2GHZ, 16GB Ram and 500GB SSD which was installed about a year ago.

These problems have only come up with El Capitan. I didn’t have them in the past with Yosemite. Downgrading is likely to be a problem as Migration Assistant gives problems when trying to port the data across by telling you that Time Machine is working off a later version of OsX.

Looking around online, I can see that many people have had similar issues but the resolutions that have worked for them unfortunately have not worked for me.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is off-topic and should be submitted to the superuser or apple stackexchange sites.

Comment: I vote for it to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

The correct `chown` syntax is

```
chown 0 /private/etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Life saver! Thanks.

Comment: And how do you run this? In single user mode, the file system is mounted as read-only. In recovery mode, there is no system prompt to run this from.

Comment: The `mount -uw` command (given in the question) should re-mount the root filesystem read-write in single user mode.

Answer (score 0):

try running the command from another operating system, so for example from a mac os x 10.9, or 10.10 partition:

```
sudo chown 0 /Volumes/NAME_OF_VOLUME/private/etc/sudoers
```

This is what worked for me. you might also be able to do this from a 10.9, or 10.10 recovery usb environment.